# How to inner join 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, inner-join, create-view

I'm having trouble with creating a view using the Inner Join, i have these 3 tables

- Projects (ProjID, ProjName, InitDate, EndDate)
- Employees (EmpID, EmpName, Phone, City, Salary)
- Assign (ProjID, EmpID, Hours, Status, Date)

What i am triying to do is to create a view with the name "View1" to show me these information:

- (ProjID / ProjName / EmpName / Hours) only with the employees who has
  a Project ID (ProjID) that begins with "N".

I used this query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view1 AS

SELECT
    projects.ProjID,
    projects.ProjName,
    employees.EmpName,
    assign.Hours
FROM
    assign
    INNER JOIN employees ON employees.EmpID = assign.EmpID
    INNER JOIN projects
WHERE
    projects.ProjID LIKE "N%";
```

The result i got is not working and it shows multiple times the same employee with different Projects ID

Comment: Unfortunately MySQL supports inner join without `ON`, but it's essencially a cross join. Specify an `ON` condition for projects too. Looks like it should be `INNER JOIN projects on projects.ProjID = assign.ProjID`.

Comment: If I can give you a tip on the side: use full names. No use in abbreviating ProjectId to ProjId. Later on you will wonder whether it was ProjectId, ProjId, PrjId or something else, and the time it costs later on will be more than you would spend on just typing the full name.

Comment: "The result i got is not working and it shows multiple times the same employee with different Projects ID" - that's by-design due to the cardinality of the relationship you have between Employees and Projects (via `Assign`). Please post some desired example output data so we can understand what you really want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, friend. It showed me the right results inmediately. I will follow your advice with the columns naming. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use this query

```
select * 
from employees
inner join assign on employees.EmpID=assign.EmpID
inner join projects on projects.ProjID=assign.ProjID
where projects.ProjID LIKE "N%";
```

the difference with your query is that you need to establish the relation between projects and assignments.

Anyway if you have the same employee assigned to more than one project that match the where clause, you will get that employee more than once.
Maybe you should group and use some aggregation formula like sum(hours)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v1 AS
(
    SELECT p.ProjID, p.ProjName, e.EmpName, a.Hours
    FROM Projects p
    INNER JOIN Assign a ON a.ProjID=p.ProjID
    INNER JOIN Emplyees e ON e.EmpID = a.EmpID
    WHERE p.ProjID LIKE "N%";
);
```

I would like to remind that if you will SUM(a.Hours)
you will have to group the other projections.